# How S3 putObject "expires" works?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

S3's `putObject` method from [AWS SDK for PHP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#putobject) states that I can pass a `Expires` parameter that specifies

> The date and time at which the object is no longer cacheable.

I'm confused by that... what does it mean exactly?

I thought that the object's bucket, key and URL stays the same forever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That info is [used by CloudFront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html) to know how long to cache objects from S3. Or if you are serving a static website from S3 without CloudFront, it would be used by browsers to determine how long to cache a file in the local browser cache.

Comment: `Expires` is also read by browsers, but it is deprecated in favor of `Cache-Control`.